# Can Spark read former part of parquet file without reading it all to memory？

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, parquet

Assume we have a parquet file(or other any file) P which have some columns and rows. File P have a column named A which have 0 or 1 only. Moreover, rows have column A as 0 is only 1% of this file. We want to read rows whose column A is 0.

The simplest way to do is do read it all and the use `where` to filter A as 1. This way cost a too much because we actually want only 1% of file P. We can't either write P into two files include A as 0 and A as 1 before reading it. This look like impossible if you don't read it into memory, how can you filter it ?

If we let file P sort by column A before write it into disk, we can have A as 0 in the former part of file P. In this situation, Can Spark read rows whose A is 0 only?

Comment: Maybe Predicate push-down in Parquet can satisfy my need. Right?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on the file format you're talking about, and on the way the file has been partitioned. Let's discuss parquet files:

#### Filtering on partition column

If your file has been written like so:

```scala
df.write.partitionBy("A").parquet(filename)
```

This is the best case scenario. Your file will have been written in a way that `spark.read.parquet(filename).filter(col("A") === 0)` will only read in the wanted data. The reason why this is possible is because the parquet file has a subdirectory for each value of the `A` column. So it's perfectly possible to not read in the directory where `A == 1`.

#### Filtering on a non-partition column

This is where the file format you're using has an impact. In the case of parquet files, there is some filtering that is also pushed down to reading the file.

Parquet files are chopped up in row groups. For each row group, parquet files keep some metadata (including min/max of that row group). This allows for skipping of row groups (imagine you want to read in only values where `A == 0` and the min value is `1`, you can skip that whole row group).

For CSV files, for example, this second one is not possible.